# page not redirecting to the location in the <a href=""> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li data-submenu-id="submenu-patas"> <a href="products.html">Books & Audible <span style="float:right; padding-left:10px; padding-top:2px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                  <div id="submenu-patas" class="popover nav_bg_books">
                    <h3 class="popover-title">Books & Audible</h3>
                    <ul style="float:left; z-index:999; ">
                      <h5 style="color:#C30">Books</h5>
                      <li><a href="products.html">Books</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="products.html">Textbooks</a></li>
                      <li><a href="products.html">Magazine</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul style="float:left; z-index:999;">
                      <h5  style="color:#C30">Audible</h5>
                      <li><a href="products.html">Audible Audiobooks</a></li>
                      <li><a href="products.html">Books with Audio Companions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
</ul>
```

I have a html content like above. when i mouse over Books & Audible it will show its sub items.but when i click on the main or its sub category its is not redirecting to the corresponding page

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: It's working in the fiddle.

Comment: you may be using prevent default in you js  click handlers

Comment: @Emre Acar can you give me the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqzc8k8t/embedded/result/